# Is there a way to move the camera of a 2d world in pyglet?

Tags: python-3.x, 2d, viewport, pyglet

I'm testing pyglet, and it has everything(except for a good guide) but the only thing that i don't understand is: how do I move the camera to show hidden content?

Comment: Please provide some code. Do you use legacy OpenGL (`glBegin`/`glEnd`) or do you use a shader program? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, i'll take it in count, i use legacy OpenGL

Comment: Start with [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) and [`glTranslatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes since the pyglet 2 update, you can now use `Window.view = Window.view.from_translation(pygmath.Vec3(xpos, ypos, zpos))`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Rabbid76, try pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(dx,dy,dz).

The first argument in glTranslatef changes the x-direction of a supposed "camera",
the second changes y, and the third changes z. Heres a quick code example that may also help:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet.gl import glTranslatef  

def movement(keys):
    if keys[key.I]:
        glTranslatef(0,10,0)
    if keys[key.K]:
        glTranslatef(0,-10,0)
    if keys[key.J]:
        glTranslatef(-10,0,0)
    if keys[key.L]:
        glTranslatef(10,0,0)

def update(dt):
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
    movement()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = pyglet.window.Window(height=1000,width=1000)
    keys = key.KeyStateHandler()
    window.push_handlers(keys)
    label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2)

    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update,1/60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

In the above example, you would use the I, J, K, and L keys to move a label around your window. Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an offset. Fo/x, lets say x = 0, and camoffset = 5. You can render the x as x+camoffset. It works.